# How do I return JSON from an action in CFWheels?

Tags: json, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I've been reading a lot about returning JSON in CFWheels...it all looks straight forward, but all I ever get is a blank page with no JSON returned. I may be doing something really obviously wrong here.

Here's my action:

```
public void function ajax() { 

    param name="params.keyword" default="";

    onlyProvides("json");

    pins = model("pin").findAll(

        include     = "user", 
        order       = "createdat DESC",
        where       = "title LIKE '%#cleanInput(application.jsoup, params.keyword)#%'"

    );

    renderWith(data=pins, layout=false);

}
```

I can confirm that searching on a word and dumping the query result reveals a record, but when it's like above, all I get is a blank screen. Am I missing something here?

I want to return the query object in JSON. Is there something I have to actually output in my view? I could do this, but wante to do it all from the action as I thought it would?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Comment: Looks like I just had to clear and reload CFWheels, which is odd, since everything in the action worked fine. Hmm.

Comment: I'm thinking you don't need `layout=false`. Also, do you have a call to `provides()` in the `init()` method of your controller?

Comment: @ChrisPeters For some reason, I did need layout false...I do have provides() in the init. The issue was that I wasn't passing the format=json argument. That sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head are you passing Format=JSON in your ajax call? If not the controller will not return JSON.